# Use of JavaScript in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to write some JavaScript code in my .aspx page but I have attached that .aspx page with master page. I don't see any `<div>`, `<body>`, etc. tags like normal .aspx pages. Where should I add that code now?

Comment: I think you're going to need to elaborate on this... by a lot.

Comment: You are going to need to example this with just enough code to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a master page the content pages will (generally) just contain what's in the form in the body element.

You can add a content placeholder in the head of the master page:

```
  ...
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" />
</head>
...
```

That allows you to add content in the head from your content pages. Example:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<script>
alert('Hello, world.');
</scipt>
</asp:Content>
```